# Implementing Google maps into xml file error?

Tags: java, android

I am coding Google maps v2 into my app but have run into an error.
I have already included the API key in the manifest.

Whenever I click on "Map" from the list on the menu for my app the application crashes:
Below is the errors shown in LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(2041): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(2041): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.anonymous.anonymous1/com.anonymous.anonymous1.Activity_Map}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class fragment
```

This is the relevant Java and xml file:
http://pastebin.com/LkjrHkPy

Does anyone know how to resolve this error so i can see the map on my application?
I think it may have something to do with the xml containing a fragment.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? If you're using an emulator, is it running the Google APIs?

Comment: @Nachi
You mean this?
http://pastebin.com/zeSj0JK6
I am using a nexus device, not an emulator

Comment: Yep, your real error is _java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"_. [This](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon the `ClassNotFoundException`, you need to add the Android library project for the Google Play Services to your app: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: I have imported the google play services but it doesn't work since I already have a MainActivity

Comment: @user1892991: Your stack trace does not refer to `MainActivity`. You can tell this by searching your stack trace for `MainActivity` and not finding it. Also, the Google Play Services library project does not have a `MainActivity`.